# How can I calculate time through Ajax | PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have the script to upload the files but I need to add a time counter feature and I can not, can you help ?

```
function uploadFile(){
var file = _("file-7").files[0];
// alert(file.name+" | "+file.size+" | "+file.type);
var formdata = new FormData();
formdata.append("file", file);
var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
ajax.upload.addEventListener("progress", progressHandler, false);
ajax.addEventListener("load", completeHandler, false);
ajax.addEventListener("error", errorHandler, false);
ajax.addEventListener("abort", abortHandler, false);
ajax.open("POST", "index.php");
ajax.send(formdata); }
```

During the upload, the script stops and does not complete, reaches 100MB and stops? What's the reason ?

Site: https://upshorty.cool-scripts.com

And there is a problem, the more you refresh the page, the file is reloaded and uploaded and this is a defect

Script:

```
 } else {
        if(in_array($fileActualExt, $preview_types)) { 
        $preview =  generate_random_string(10).".".$fileActualExt;
        } else {
        $preview = null;
        }
        $delete_token = generate_random_string(30);
        clearstatcache();
        $fileNewName = uniqid(true).".".$fileActualExt;
        $exp = explode(".", $fileNewName);
        $link_id = $exp[0];
        $fileDestination = 'up/'.$fileNewName;
        move_uploaded_file($fileTmpName, $fileDestination);
        $db->query("INSERT INTO files (name, size, type, type_name, uniqid, id_user, statut, link_id, date, delete_token, preview) VALUES ('$fileName', '$fileSize', '$fileActualExt', '$fileType', '$fileNewName', '$id_user', '0', '$url_key', '$long_date', '$delete_token', '$preview')");
       ?>
```

Comment: And if you can also calculate the speed of upload in a second?

Comment: By "time counter" do you mean how long the upload takes?

Comment: Yes, how much is expected to take the time to upload the file

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `Date()` object at the beginning of upload. 
e.g. `var start = new Date();` then `start` would be the starting time. When the upload finishes, use another `Date()` object to mark its finishing time. e.g. `var end = new Date();` then `end` would be the ending time. Then calculate the time used by `var t = start - end;`, the result `t` would be in milliseconds.

You may further calculate the upload speed by getting the file size and divide it by `t/1000` (since t is in milliseconds).